# dynamic list containing another dynamic list in react

Tags: reactjs

it seems like a stupid question but its been bugging me for a while now.

assume that my render function displays a list like so:

```
render(){
return (
  <div>
  <button onClick={()=>{this.setState({dummyList2:[...this.state.dummyList2,<h2>world</h2>]})}}> add to dummy list 2 </button>
   {this.state.dummyList1.map(el=>el)}
  </div>
)
```

and my state in the constructor is as follows:

```
state={
dummyList2:[]
dummyList1:[<h1>{this.state.dummyList2.map(el=>el)}</h1>]
}
```

the behavior I expect is clicking the button would add item to `dummyList2` and since I am rendering `dummyList1` which contains the second list, it should display the updated elements however this is not working and I'm not sure why

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

For a better view of what I am trying to achieve, I have created a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-cohen-21k5l)

Comment: You have to use `prevState` while assigning the new element to the array. If you don't do so it may lead to inconsistency. Also, where do you have `dummyList2` inside `dummyList1`?

Comment: @luckongas I'm trying to simplify my issue as much i can :D. basically what i am doing is i have a `react-grid-layout` component and what i am trying to do is have nested ones

basically the idea is i have a toolbox through which a user can drag items to the parent grid and can also drag items to the child grid as well .. i succeeded in updating the state i can see it changing and the `componentDidUpdate` is getting fired however the .map for the the line where i call `{this.state.dummyList2.map(el=>el)}` is only getting called once. state update isnt getting picked up

Comment: since I am rendering the parent grid layout's children with a map and then when a user drags a second grid layout inside the parent grid layout  the children render of the second grid layout is done with a map as well.

Comment: Can you provide a full component example?  From what you have shown when you set dummy list 1 to use dummy list 2,. Dummy list 2 is empty. As the constructor does not get called after initialization you will need to update dummy list 1 inside componentDidUpdate.

Comment: While setting the state, you are doing it on `dummyList2`, so why is supposed to be re-rendered `dummyList1` with any new elements?

Comment: @sam I have created a sandbox link for you to checkout, as you can see the dummylist2 and the componentDidUpdate are getting fired however the components dont render on the screen. the .map is executed only once , what i want to do is hook it to the state? somehow :D

Comment: @luckongas since what I am trying to achieve is get list 1 to render a list of dynamic children that can be added with a click of a button. it is getting executed only once so i am not sure how i can get it to detect the list2 change and append those to the existing list1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked your code. By doing on the constructor this:

```js
this.state = {
  ...this.state,
  dummyList1: [
    <div>
      <h1>hello</h1>
      {this.state.dummyList2.map((el) => el)}
    </div>
  ]
};
```

You are creating a copy of the dummyList2 and It's not going to be re-render because it's resolved on the constructor, so is not going to be updated. What's happening is that after the component constructor is executed the `dummyList1` is

```js
dummyList1: [
  <div>
    <h1>hello</h1>
    <h2>world</h2>
  </div>
]
```

without any reference to `dummyList2`

If you are trying to render the `dummyList2` components inside the HTML that you put inside `dummyList1` I'll suggest passing the `dummyList2` as a child as I did in [this example](https://codesandbox.io/s/still-worker-w7dq7)

Hope it helps. Anything else that I can help you with let me know.